# Simulate "Windows" key and "+" key to zoom in

Tags: c#, automation, autoit, keystroke

Windows 7 (finally) has built-in zoom feature for the screen. Hold down the "Windows" key and you can then use the "+" key to zoom in and the "-" key to zoom out. As a result I have been trying to simulate this combination. With AutoIt I have tried:

1)

```
Send("{LWINDOWN}" & "+" & "{LWINUP}")
```

2)

```
$x = Chr(43)
Send("{LWINDOWN}" & $x & "{LWINUP}")
```

3)

```
Send("#{+}") ;//works but it also sends "+" key
```

4)

```
Send("{LWINDOWN}")
Sleep(10)
Send("+",1)
Sleep(10)
Send("{LWINUP}")
```

**None of those 4 steps work...**

I actually want to use this functionality on c#. If I manage to do it with autoit I could invoke that script with c# so I don't mind the langauage. I am also simulating keystrokes because I don't know how I will be able to zoom in using c#.

Comment: Process.Start("Magnify.exe");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the library located at:

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

then do:

```
 WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown
                          (WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
 WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress
                          (WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.OEM_PLUS);
 WindowsInput.InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp
                          (WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode.LWIN);
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it right ... the actual syntax is Send("{LWIN DOWN}" & "+" & "{LWIN UP}").

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

`SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");`

If you want to call it to somewindow you can use

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and then

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Some.exe");

        foreach(Process proc in processes)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");
        }
```