# Bring up the emoji panel from Delphi code

Tags: delphi, emoji

I want to bring up the Windows 10 emoji panel for a `TEdit`/`TMemo` from a speed button click.  Could be done by simulating the Win+. key combo, but I'm not sure how to simulate the windows key.

The Emoji panel is shown below.

[image: Windows 10 Emoji Panel]

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962262/programmatically-launching-windows-10-emoji-hotkeys?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
  keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0); // Left Win down
  keybd_event(190, 0, 0, 0); // "." down
  keybd_event(190, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // "." up
  keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Left Win up
```

as does (based on Remy's suggestion)

```
procedure ShowEmoji;
var
  k: array [0..3] of TInput;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@k,sizeof(k));

  for I := low(k) to high(k) do
   k[i].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;

  k[0].ki.wVk := VK_LWIN;
  k[1].ki.wVk := 190;
  k[2].ki.wVk := 190;
  k[2].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  k[3].ki.wVk := VK_LWIN;
  k[3].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

  SendInput(Length(k), k[0], SizeOf(TInput));
end;
```

But if there is a better suggestion...

Comment: Don’t use `keybd_event()`, it is long deprecated. Use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.